# :hover not working, I've tried with everything I can think of

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a Container in a div with WoodMineOwned id, when my mouse hovers over it I want the Wood ToolTip to show but it won't

```html
<!-- TAB 1 ~Mines~-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">
    ~<span class="textCenter">Buy Mines</span>~
    <div class="tabContent tab1">
      <h2 class="textCenter">Buy Menu</h2>

      <div class="mines container2">
        <div class="minesContainer">
          <div class="minesOwned" id="woodMineOwned">Wood Mine: 0</div>

          <div class="minesOwned" id="stoneMineOwned">Stone Mine: 0</div>

          <div class="minesOwned" id="coalMineOwned">Coal Mine: 0</div>

          <div class="minesOwned" id="ironMineOwned">Iron Mine: 0</div>

          <div class="minesOwned" id="silverMineOwned">Silver Mine: 0</div>

          <div class="minesOwned" id="goldMineOwned">Gold Mine: 0</div>

          <div class="minesOwned" id="diamondMineOwned">Diamond Mine: 0</div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <!-- Wood ToolTip -->
  <div class="tipWoodMine" id="tipWoodMine" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Wood Mine</h3>
    <p>Cost: 100 Wood | 50 Stone <span style="color: red">(+7%)</span></p>
    <p>Wood Per Second: 0 <span style="color: green">(+1)</span></p>
    <p>Owned: 0 <span style="color: green">(+1)</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.tab {
   position: relative;
   flex: 1;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
}

.tabContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 392%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    
}

.tab:hover .tabContent {
    display: block;
}

.minesOwned {
    font-size: 75%;
    flex-basis: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.textCenter {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Tool Tips */
.tipWoodMine {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    height: 155px; 
    text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

#woodMineOwned:hover ~ .tipWoodMine {
    display: "block";
}
```

That's all the code I think is needed to show. Sorry for it being long: I want the tooltip to show when I hover over the wood mine but it just won't appear as a block. Is it because the WoodMine Owned is in a container and the ToolTip that I made is not in the container div?

Comment: Read into specificity weight. CSS can not overwrite inline-stlye without !important. A reason why you should not mix it in the first place.

Comment: @tacoshy sorry im pretty new to coding, can you give me an example of a work around or how to use this !important rule to fix it? it would help a ton.

Comment: Great resources [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to learn about specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons why your attempt isn't working:

- [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `~` doesn't match `.tipWoodMine` because it is not a sibling
- You have `display: "block";` but `"block"` is not a valid value
- `style="display: none;"` inline overrules the stylesheet declarations

To achieve the desired result:

- Move the tooltip container to be the adjacent sibling of the mine container
- You can use a more generic class name (instead of unique classes for each) along with the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `+` to display the tooltip

```css
.tip {
  display: none;
}

.minesOwned:hover + .tip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="minesOwned" id="woodMineOwned">Wood Mine: 0</div>

<!-- Wood ToolTip -->
<div class="tip">
  <h3>Wood Mine</h3>
  <p>Cost: 100 Wood | 50 Stone <span style="color: red">(+7%)</span></p>
  <p>Wood Per Second: 0 <span style="color: green">(+1)</span></p>
  <p>Owned: 0 <span style="color: green">(+1)</span></p>
</div>

<div class="minesOwned" id="stoneMineOwned">Stone Mine: 0</div>

<!-- Stone ToolTip -->
<div class="tip">
  <h3>Stone Mine</h3>
  <p>Cost: 100 Wood | 50 Stone <span style="color: red">(+7%)</span></p>
  <p>Stone Per Second: 0 <span style="color: green">(+1)</span></p>
  <p>Owned: 0 <span style="color: green">(+1)</span></p>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* justify-content: space-around; */
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.tab {
 /* position: relative; */
 /* flex: 1; */
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.tabContent {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 100%; */
  /* width: 392%; */
  /* height: 300px; */
  /* background-color: #f9f9f9; */
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  
}

.tab:hover .tabContent {
  display: block;
}

.minesOwned {
  font-size: 75%;
  /* flex-basis: 30%; */
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.textCenter {
  /* text-align: center; */
}

/* Tool Tips */
.tip {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  /* width: 40%; */
  /* height: 155px; */
  /* text-align: center; */
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.minesOwned:hover + .tip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- TAB 1 ~Mines~-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">
    ~Buy Mines~
    <div class="tabContent tab1">
      <h2>Buy Menu</h2>

      <div class="minesContainer">
        <div class="minesOwned" id="woodMineOwned">Wood Mine: 0</div>

        <!-- Wood ToolTip -->
        <div class="tip">
          <h3>Wood Mine</h3>
          <p>Cost: 100 Wood | 50 Stone <span style="color: red">(+7%)</span></p>
          <p>Wood Per Second: 0 <span style="color: green">(+1)</span></p>
          <p>Owned: 0 <span style="color: green">(+1)</span></p>
        </div>

        <div class="minesOwned" id="stoneMineOwned">Stone Mine: 0</div>

        <!-- Stone ToolTip -->
        <div class="tip">
          <h3>Stone Mine</h3>
          <p>Cost: 100 Wood | 50 Stone <span style="color: red">(+7%)</span></p>
          <p>Stone Per Second: 0 <span style="color: green">(+1)</span></p>
          <p>Owned: 0 <span style="color: green">(+1)</span></p>
        </div>

        <div class="minesOwned" id="coalMineOwned">Coal Mine: 0</div>

        <div class="minesOwned" id="ironMineOwned">Iron Mine: 0</div>

        <div class="minesOwned" id="silverMineOwned">Silver Mine: 0</div>

        <div class="minesOwned" id="goldMineOwned">Gold Mine: 0</div>

        <div class="minesOwned" id="diamondMineOwned">Diamond Mine: 0</div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Issue with the CSS selector! use the adjacent sibling selector `+` instead of `~` because the tooltip is not a sibling of the `#woodMineOwned element`, it's a child of a different container

the corrected code will be

```
#woodMineOwned:hover + .tipWoodMine {
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This will still not work due to the inline style of the element being `display: none`. Also `+` and `~` both select _on the same level_. The only difference is that `~` selects any element coming after the selector, while `+` only selects the first after the selector, so not sure what you are on about here.